# FirebaseUser currentUser is exist, in code even it is manually deleted from Firebase DB

Tags: android, firebase

How is it possible?
I deleted User from Authentication, and Database from Firebase portal.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user

After when I debug my app,

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

if (currentUser == null) {
    sendToStartActivity();
}
```

currentUser is not null, but there is nothing in my Firebase DB. How is it possible? Isn't it real time syncing?

Comment: Just because it exists doesn't mean there has to be anything in it. Did you actually delete everything and not just the associated data?

Comment: @Zoe Thanks for the very very quick reply. Yes, I deleted everything in Firebase.Authantication, Database & Storage.

Comment: How exactly is this different from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55206819/4916627)?

Comment: @PoojaSingh Don't repost the same question please.