# How to delete FirebaseUser currentuser from Firebase Console?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I deleted everything from Authentication, Database and Storage (Realtime Database) but still currentUser is showing not null, when I debug my app. What else is remaining?

See: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user][1]

code:

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


        if (currentUser == null) {
            sendToStartActivity();
        }


 @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            databaseReference.child(USERS).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(ONLINE).setValue(TRUE);
            showLog("onStart: MainActivity");
        } else {
            sendToStartActivity();
        }
    }
```

Comment: try clearing your applications cache on your device or uninstall it and try

Comment: How you're deleting everything?

Comment: @Heisenberg In Firebase website: Authentication: delete user; Database: delete all data by clicking cross button

Comment: @PraveenGM then what is the use of Firebase realtime sync?

Comment: Okay, that means you are deleting user directly from `Firebase Console`, not from the application?

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes, so when I close the app, delete user from Firebase and open app again, then my app should go to StartActivity from MainActivity, if that user is null. But user is not showing null.

Comment: @PraveenGM Ofcourse, when I uninstall & install again then it is working properly. But then what is the difference between SQL & firebase?

Comment: First thing sorry for asking, but is your device is connected to working network connection? And Second thing, check local preference storage of firebase is still available or not.

Comment: Firebase Authentication tokens are valid for one hour and cached on the user's device. It is automatically refreshed by the client SDK. Deleting the account doesn't proactively reach out to all the user's devices to delete the token.

However, if you then try to read or write data that requires authentication, that should fail when using the cached token.

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes, it is connected to Internet (I tried for other things, like I deleted another user from Firebase console, and immediate effect I can see in my app. yes user is removed, so no issue for Internet/syncing). Second, How do I check storage of Firebase?

Comment: @PraveenGM What exactly should I do?

Comment: @PoojaSingh Firebase does the sync automatically, when user opens the app first time or if user is not signed in, currentUser returns null and the user is redirected to StartActivity. So your code is perfectly fine there is nothing need to be done

Comment: @PraveenGM then why it is directly going to MainActivity instead of StartActivity?

Comment: i didnt get you, only when user is not signed in the user is redirected to StartActivity if thats what you asked for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190198/discussion-between-praveen-gm-and-pooja-singh).

Comment: have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53429705/2289835) that displays to delete use from firebase?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution?