# What is the difference between Firebase currentUser signed out and deleted user from Firebase DB?

Tags: android, firebase

When you do `currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser`, we can check whether currentUser is null or not, if not null means signed in. What if user is deleted manually from Firebase console? How can I check that if user is deleted or not?

Comment: Instead of asking the same question in a different way it would be better if you edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55206819/4916627) to give some more context about what (and perhaps why) you are trying to do and what problems you are having. This will make it easier for other people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
mFirebaseUser.reload().addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
    if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException) {
        Log.d(TheApp.LOG_TAG, "User doesn't exist");
    }
}});
```